# TypeAlias a class contained in NSKeyedArchiver file

Tags: swift, type-alias, nskeyedunarchiver

My app uses a file created with `NSKeyArchiver`, it has a reference to an object that is contained in an external Framework.  The external Framework is no longer is available in the app Xcode project.  So when I attempt to load the archive file, the app will crash when attempting to resolve the type of this object.  i.e `MyMobileKit_Token`

I was wondering if it's possible to create a 'local' instance of the object type in the app, then using the typealias fool the unarchive operation to reference the local type i.e Token

Or would I have to create a new 'proxy' Framework project with this one class and add the proxy framework to my app project keeping the naming of the framework and class exactly the same.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I found the answer.  I created a class called `Token` with the same properties in the framework.  Then I added the following line before opening the archive file:

`NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(Token.self, forClassName: "MyMobileKit.Token")`

Seemed to work out.